# Python Pickling Slots Error

Tags: python, pickle

I have a large instance that I've been pickling just fine, but recently I started getting this error when I tried to dump it:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 77, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError("a class that defines __slots__ without "
TypeError: a class that defines __slots__ without defining __getstate__ cannot be pickled
```

I don't understand this error, since all my classes seem to define a `__getstate__` method, and none seem to define `__slots__`. I'm having trouble isolating the change I made the triggered this error.

I can only assume there's some object nested deep within my instance that's causing this. Is there any way to get more info? How do I find the class of the exact object that's triggering this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204155/why-am-i-getting-an-error-about-my-class-defining-slots-when-trying-to-pickl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a binary protocol for your pickling (instead of the old ASCII one you seem to be defaulting to) and you'll be fine.  Observe:

```
>>> class ws(object):
...   __slots__ = 'a', 'b'
...   def __init__(self, a=23, b=45): self.a, self.b = a, b
... 
>>> x = ws()
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(x, -1)
'\x80\x02c__main__\nws\nq\x00)\x81q\x01N}q\x02(U\x01aq\x03K\x17U\x01bq\x04K-u\x86q\x05b.'
>>> pickle.dumps(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [[snip]]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 77, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError("a class that defines __slots__ without "
TypeError: a class that defines __slots__ without defining __getstate__ cannot be pickled
>>>
```

As you see, the `-1` protocol (which means "the best, fastest and most compact protocol") works just fine, while the default `0` protocol (the old ascii protocol designed to be compatible all the way back to Python 1.5 and earlier) gives exactly the exception you have observed.

Besides, `-1` will be faster *and* produce more compact results -- you just need to ensure you correctly save and restore the **binary** strings it produces (so, for example, if you're pickling to file, be sure to open the latter for `wb`, *not* just `w`).

If for some reason this all-around-win solution is not available to you, there are hacks and tricks (e.g., subclass `pickle.Pickler`, use directly an instance of your subclass rather than the base one as `pickle.dumps` does, override the `save` method so it traces the `type(obj)` before delegating to the superclass), but upgrading to the right, most up-to-date protocol (`-1` is guaranteed to be, on any given Python version, the most advanced one that version supports) would be a good idea anyway, if at all feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also but with some already pickled data in the Old ASCII protocol  .
You can use these methods to adapt slot to your object:

```
class MyAlreadyPickeldObjectWithslots(object):
    ___slots__= ("attr1","attr2",....)
    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict([(k, getattr(self,k,None)) for k in self.__slots__])

    def __setstate__(self,data):
        for k,v in data.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
```

That's can be usefull to gain amount of RAM

Comment: `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` do not need to use a `dict`. So, it may be efficient to use a list and zip with `__slots__` on assignment.