# Load pickle string in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to loads a pickle string in python3.8,but `pickle.loads` get error `_pickle.UnpicklingError: slot state is not a dictionary`,this string is read from postgresql,In python2 it is working, I found python3's version pickle only support loads bytes type data,but python2 support `str` type.
I used `six` library to loads string, but get a another error `UnpicklingError: slot state is not a dictionary`,I tried to print slot, it is a list type object,thats a confused problem.
my python2 code:

```
a = ""  # the dumps string
result = pickle.loads(a)  # its working
print "result type", type(result)  # <type 'dict'>
```

python3 code:

```
a = ""
result = pickle.loads(a.encode('utf-8'), fix_imports=True, encoding='utf-8')
# error: _pickle.UnpicklingError: slot state is not a dictionary
```

Comment: You might be defaulting to the old ASCII protocol. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409767

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of an empty string does not produce the equivalent of a pickled empty string therefore pickle.loads() can't make sense of the input bytes.

Consider this:

```
import pickle

STRING = ''

p = pickle.dumps(STRING)
print(len(p))
print('>', pickle.loads(p), '<', sep='')
```

**Output:**

```
15
><
```

**Note:**

Note that the number of bytes needed to represent a pickled empty string is 15

Comment: thank you your answer my question,finally I found this mistake because the old python2 code generated result have some mistake,thats very stupid