# Pickle: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror, pickle

I found a lot of threads about this but the problem of all of them is the namespace. My problem have nothing to do with namespace.

A small example:

```
import cPickle as pickle
from uncertainties import Variable

class value(Variable):
    def __init__(self, args, showing=False):
        self.show = showing
        Variable.__init__(self, args[0], args[1])

val = value((3,1), True)
print val.nominal_value, val.std_dev(), val.show
fobj = file("pickle.file", "w")
pickle.dump(val, fobj)
fobj.close()

fobj = file("pickle.file", "r")
val = pickle.load(fobj)
fobj.close()
print val.nominal_value, val.std_dev(), val.show
```

The output of this code:

```
3.0 1.0 True
3.0 1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/markus/pickle.py in <module>()
     19 val = pickle.load(fobj)
     20 fobj.close()
---> 21 print val.nominal_value, val.std_dev(), val.show

AttributeError: 'value' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The namespace is the same at pickling and unpickling. All attributes of `uncertainties.Variable` are restored - only my added one "show" is missed.

Comment: What is the `uncertainties` module? Where does it come from?

Comment: Are you able to come up with a self-contained example of this, i.e. one that we can experiment with?

Comment: @NPE: I was able to reproduce it once I located the [`uncertainties` project](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/); it uses a custom `__getstate__` method.

Comment: I was not allowed to post links as new user. But I found this module on original python.org page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncertainties/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`uncertainties.Variable()` class](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/blob/master/uncertainties/__init__.py#L1203) uses a [`__slots__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to save memory. As a result, to be pickleable, it *must* define a [`__getstate__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) as well (see [Why am I getting an error about my class defining __slots__ when trying to pickle an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204155/why-am-i-getting-an-error-about-my-class-defining-slots-when-trying-to-pickl)).

If you need to add your own additional attributes, you'll have to override that `__getstate__` method. Declaring your additional attributes in a `__slot__` attribute of your own is probably a good idea too:

```
from uncertainties import Variable

class value(Variable):
    __slots__ = ('show',)  # only list *additional* slots

    def __init__(self, args, showing=False):
        self.show = showing
        super(value, self).__init__(args[0], args[1])

    def __getstate__(self):
        obj_slot_values = {}
        for cls in type(self).mro():
            obj_slot_values.update((k, getattr(self, k)) for k in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ()))
        # Conversion to a usual dictionary:
        return obj_slot_values
```

This new `__getstate__` is required because the `Variable.__getstate__` method assumes that there will only be *one* `__slots__` attribute, while each class in the MRO may have one instead.

This is really a limitation of the `uncertainties` library; I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/pull/13) that addresses this and would remove the need to override the `__getstate__` method in a subclass.

Comment: OK, "simple" way but hard to find with this general AttributeError. Thank a lot.

Comment: @Chickenmarkus: Thanks to Martijn, who sent me a patch, the latest Github version of uncertainties makes your `value` class directly pickeable without having to define your own `__getstate__()`.

Comment: @Chickenmarkus: I just uploaded version 1.9.1 of my uncertainties package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncertainties/): your subclass should now be directly pickleable (no need to define your own `__getstate__`.

Comment: @EOL: Yes, with version 1.9.1 my first example works now too. Thanks.